# How to limit number of threads used by NumPy's OpenBlas on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, numpy, openblas

I'm analyzing time of scripts execution in Python and I want to turn off MKL/OpenBLAS optimization. How to do it properly on Windows?

I have Windows 10 x64 with Python 3.6 and numpy 1.16.3 installed via pip.

I've tried setting system env variables on Windows (`OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS`, `MKL_NUM_THREADS`, `NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS`, `VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS`), and in Python script:

```
import os

os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```

but executing this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
N = 10**4
a = np.random.random((N, N))
b = a@a
```

still uses more threads than one.

My `np.__config__.show()` looks like this:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\projects\\numpy-wheels\\numpy\\build\\openblas']
    libraries = ['openblas']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\projects\\numpy-wheels\\numpy\\build\\openblas']
    libraries = ['openblas']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\projects\\numpy-wheels\\numpy\\build\\openblas']
    libraries = ['openblas']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['C:\\projects\\numpy-wheels\\numpy\\build\\openblas']
    libraries = ['openblas']
    language = f77
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

On my PC there is no path like `C:\\projects\\numpy-wheels\\numpy\\build\\openblas`, it must be a path from the machine on which the library was compiled.

My trick to achieve execution on one thread is to run script from CMD like this:

```
start /affinity 0x4 python script.py
```

but it's not the correct way to manage math library optimizations (and I'm not sure if this command really limits OpenBLAS).

Comment: You should set env variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`

Comment: I tried - it didn't work.